# Step into STL sources in Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, stl, step-into

I've been using Xcode 5 for a while now and I can't figure out how to debug into the STL source headers. The option "Step Into" (F7) just skips over the statement I would like the debugger to step into, and I don't find a setting to change this behavior. I remember people complaining about previous versions of Xcode where stepping into the STL sources could not be turned off... it's frustrating.

Comment: I assume you're building *debug* bits, right? because part of the beauty of the standard library is its incredible propensity to inline huge chunks of its code when optimized in release-builds. Thus, there is nothing to "step into".

Answer (score 17):

There is a setting in lldb that controls this:

```
(lldb) settings show target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp
target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp (regex) = ^std::
```

As you see, by default it is set not to step into anything in the std namespace.  Just make a file called `.lldbinit` in your home directory, and put in that:

```
settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ""
```

and we will no longer skip over functions in std.

Comment: Hey I realize it's been like seven years but I tried this and it works. I'd like to make sure that this doesn't affect any inlining in release builds and wanted to know if this really is just a setting that lldb doesn't step into the std namespace. Thank you if you do see this.

Comment: Yup, this is all on lldb's side.  It doesn't kick in until in the course of executing a "step in" operation lldb lands in code matching the step-avoid-regexp.  Then, instead of stopping, we schedule a "step out" and continue on with the step-in operation we were in the middle of.

Comment: Thanks man even if I was literally almost 8 years late.. I was only 7 then...